# JPA (Hibernate): "ORA-02289 Sequence does not exist", but it does

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with JPA entities.

I created a new one like this:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Entity_Sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Entity_Sequence", sequenceName = "Entity_Seq")
    private Long id;

    // ... other fields
}
```

Generated SQL I used to create DB Objects:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ENTITY_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 50;

CREATE TABLE ENTITY (
  ID     NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
  -- ... other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Now, I am able to query the nextval of the sequence from SQL Developer and from IntelliJ. But when I try to persist an entity from code, Hibernate throws the following exception:

```
15:21:11,022 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 2) Hibernate: select ENTITY_SEQ.nextval from dual
15:21:11,037 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 2) SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
15:21:11,037 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 2) ORA-02289: Sequence ist nicht vorhanden.
```

("Sequence ist nicht vorhanden" translates to "Sequence does not exist".)

Why is Hibernate not able to find the sequence while I am?

**EDIT 1 (12-01)**:
I tried the suggested [answer from Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595619/9039441), but the error is still the same.

**EDIT 2 (12-01)**:
Since Olivier deleted his answer, he suggested I move the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation to the class.

Comment: Are you sure that hibernate connects to the correct database?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes, all other entities work (which I have created a year ago, but have the same structure)

Comment: Usually Oracle is not case-sensitive, but try to put your table name in uppercase in your entity as well: `sequenceName = "ENTITY_SEQ"`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I've also tried that, still nothing. Also I use a custom NamingStrategy which transforms names to UPPER_CASE already.

Comment: Do you have several users for that database? Is it possible that you created the sequence and table with a specific user (let's call this user "admin") but are using hibernate with another user (let's call this user "app")? Then, that some scripts gives visibility to the tables to "app", but doesn't do the same with sequences?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I am only using one user for this project, and all tables and sequences belong to the same user, which I also use from the app.

Comment: Can you execute `SELECT ENTITY_SEQ.nextval FROM DUAL;` from the database?

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error: It was my local setup, so nothing useful to tell you, just check your setup.

I was "configuring" my server in files that aren't actually used by the server, and thus showed no effect.

Answer (score 0):

there could be many errors. Are there some more informations about your project configuration available?

Greetz
Dennis

Comment: Hey. Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please ask questions as comments? Refer to this guide to see how to write a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer